# Add Padding Right to Extended Line Chart in Chart.js V2

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am currently in the process of upgrading a `chart.js` line chart from v1 to v2 and came across a hurdle.

The chart data includes `customOptions` of an array of booleans under the `featured` property.

```
var chartData = {
    labels: [
      "14th Jan",
      "15th Jan",
      "16th Jan",
      "17th Jan",
      "18th Jan",
      "19th Jan"
    ],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Listing Popularity",
      data: [
        1199,
        575,
        407,
        313,
        181,
        268
      ],
    }],
    customOptions: {
      featured: [
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true
      ]
    }
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('chartjs-chart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'PPLine',
    data: chartData,
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I have created an extended version of a line chart that loops over the `featured` array in the charts `customOptions` and adds a path if the `featured` boolean returns `true`

```
Chart.controllers.PPLine = Chart.controllers.line.extend({
  draw: function () {

    var that = this;
    var helpers = Chart.helpers;
    var xScale = that._xScale;
    var ctx = that.chart.ctx;


    // Draw chart
    Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw.call(that, arguments);

    helpers.each(that.chart.data.customOptions.featured, function (featured, index) {
      var meta = that.chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
      var linePos = meta.data[index]._model.x,
        endLinePos = that.chart.options.elements.point.borderWidth + (meta.data[index + 1] ? meta.data[index + 1]._model.x : linePos);

      // Draw featured sections
      if (featured) {
        var centerX = meta.data[index]._model.x;
        var centerY = meta.data[index]._model.y;
        var radius = 30;

        // Draw boost circle
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = that.chart.data.customOptions.bumpedColour;
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

        // Add text
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.font = "10px " + that.chart.config.options.defaultFontFamily;
        ctx.fillText("Boost", centerX - (ctx.measureText('Boost').width / 2), centerY + 3);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The issue comes when the last item in the `featured` array is `true` and the path gets added to the point, visually, the path gets cut off, so I need to add some padding to the graph to prevent this.

In V1, I was able to do the following inside the extended line chart...

```
var that = this;
that.scale.xScalePaddingRight = 20;
```

However, scale is not a property within the v2 object. There is a `_xScale` property with a `paddingRight` property, but doing the following does not seem to add the desired padding, so that the path does not get cut off.

```
var that = this;
that._xScale.paddingRight = 20;
```

Here is a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/mcclosa/pen/xxbQdKr) with the issue.

I don't want to add padding right in every instance, just when the last point is featured and the path gets drawn.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add it in options:

```
layout: {
    padding: {
        right: 20
    }
}
```